# Getting redirect-cancelled-by-user error when using firebase SDK for authentication

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I followed the instructions from firebase docs: [Authenticate Using OAuth Providers with Cordova](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova), and when trying to authenticate from android device, using the firebase SDK for authentication, I got the following error: `redirect-cancelled-by-user`.
Trying to authenticate from Web, works!

code exmaple:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function() {
  return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
}).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a Google Access Token.
  // You can use it to access the Google API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
});
```

I saw a couple of alternative solutions out there, but I'm interested using the firebase SDK, so can someone please explain, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/267

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version. There was an issue with universal link detection that was fixed in 4.9.1: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.9.1

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the Firebase instructions tell you to install `cordova-universal-links-plugin-fix`, but it is not updating the `AndroidManifest.xml` file on Cordova 8.0. Installed the plugin `cordova-universal-links-plugin-fixed` and it worked perfectly! so:

```
# Plugin to handle Universal Links (Android app link redirects)
cordova plugin add cordova-universal-links-plugin-fixed --save
```